# Edittext give the new line string instead of string

Tags: android, android-edittext

> I have one edittext in my application.when i press the enter key in edittext that will be go to new line /n.My problem is get the edittext value which have "\n\n\n"(3time press enter button).But i want empty string value like "".how to solve this isuue thanks...

```
String task =editboxTask.getText().toString();
Log.i(TAG,"TaskName:"+task);
if (!checkTask.isEmpty()) {
   }
```

> Output is:

```
TaskName:"\n\n\n"
```

> But i want

```
TaskName:""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to parse the string variable. This can be done using the replace(char oldChar, char newChar) method of the String class.

```
task.replace("\n", "");
```